# Obtain BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR In Rake Task

Tags: ruby, xcode, rake

When Xcode builds a target, it exports a number of variables, including `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR`. I'm creating a Rake task in which I need the value of the `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` variable.

The option I'm currently using is adding a build phase to the Xcode project in which I write the value of the `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` variable to a file, but I prefer to not use a build phase if possible.

I have browsed the documentation of the fantastic [xcodeproj](https://rubygems.org/gems/xcodeproj) gem, but I don't believe there's an option to access the `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` variable using this gem.

Answer (score 0):

You can access environment variables in Ruby using `ENV`:

```
ENV['BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR']
```

(Rake tasks are Ruby)

You haven't said how the rake task and the xcode build are related. For example, does one call the other, and how.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an option. The Rake task is executed outside of Xcode, not during the build process. This means that the environment variable for the built products directory isn't available.

Comment: Do the xcode build and the rake task run one after another, in a shellscript or something?

Comment: No. The Rake task should be able to do its work without depending on Xcode building the project hence my question.